# Silverlight c# socket

Tags: silverlight

Has anyone gotten a silverlight socket application to run successfully over the internet? Like have a console server that listens for client.  The client uses silverlight sockets where users can go on any web browser and connect to the console server.

Answer (score 1):

Out-of-browser applications in Silverlight 4 work with sockets just fine. Our SecureBlackbox product offers implementations for various protocols (HTTPS, FTPS, SSH/SFTP, SSL/TLS) over Silverlight socket, and they work just fine. If you want to have something in browser, you need to make/modify the server to (a) listen on the port that belongs to specific port range (4502 to 4534) and (b) accept requests on another port 943 and provide a policy file. For more information about these requirements see [Microsoft document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28VS.95%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't had the chance or need to do so, a user group meeting I attended covered just this topic. You can watch the [video of the presentation here](http://live.ineta.org/Presentation/ViewVideo/167) and a [copy of the code sample here](http://www.dallasxaml.com/downloads/DallasXAMLMeeting-2010-10-05.zip).

Answer (score 1):

Try example from "Pro silverlight 4 with c#" or "Pro silverlight 3 with c#". It can be downloaded from [Apress](http://www.apress.com).
I have used exaple for silverlight 3 and it works fine.